# Does CDW insurance include TP option automatically in a car rental contract?

Tags: car-rentals, insurance

I see in a car rental contract that insurance is CDW. Does it mean that it includes TP (theft protection) option by default or I need to insist to see TP option in a contract with CDW?

Comment: By theft, do you mean the car itself being stolen?

Comment: Yes, I mean exactly this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The exact answer will depend upon the company you're renting from and the country, but as a general answer...

"CDW" (Collision Damage Waiver) generally does NOT include coverage for the car being stolen.

In some countries what is normally offered is actually "LDW" (Loss Damage Waiver) - although it may still be refereed to as CDW in some places. LDW generally DOES include coverage for Theft.

So now the question becomes "Do you need to purchase Theft Protection (TP) separately", and again the answer depends on the company/location.  In some countries, loss of the vehicle due to theft is NOT the responsibility of the renter (presuming you locked the car/etc), so there is no real need to have such coverage.  In other countries, it is your responsibility, so the coverage is recommended.

The only way to know what is and is not included by default is to research specifically for the country (and sometimes, company) you are renting in/from, or to ask the company and hope they give you the correct answer...

Answer (score 2):

CDW doesn't include TP (theft protection) automatically. The one that includes TP is LDW:

> CDW stands for Collision Damage Waiver. This type of insurance pays
>   for damage to your hired car but it usually excludes windscreens,
>   tyres, undercarriage, replacement locks, replacement keys, and towing
>   charges.  LDW represents Loss Damage Waiver (which includes CDW and
>   Theft Protection).
>   --from the site of [EasyRentCars](https://www.easyrentcars.com/blog/car-rental-knowhow/what-are-cdw-and-sli-for-rental-cars-honest-question-when-are-they-worth-buying/)

Answer (score 0):

Form the site of [europcar](https://www.europcar.com/EBE/module/render/General-Rental-Terms)

> **General Rental Terms**
>
> TW / TP (Theft Waiver / Theft Protection):
>   If chosen and indicated in the enrollment form or if included in the rate, this relieves you of your financial liability in the event of the Vehicle being stolen, except where incurred through negligence and/or breach of contract.
>
> **Subscribing to the CDW option alone does not necessarily provide this cover. TW may be mandatory in some countries and is strongly recommended in many countries.** It may be subject to a non-waivable charge.